# Sort a multi-indexed pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `census_df` with me that contains the county and state-wise data of USA. The DataFrame is suing nested indexing so that the first index represents a state while the second index gives a county and third gives a population. The DataFrame is given below.

```
                              CENSUS2010POP
STNAME    CTYNAME                          
Alabama   Alabama                   4779736
          Autauga County              54571
          Baldwin County             182265
          Barbour County              27457
          Bibb County                 22915
          Blount County               57322
          Bullock County              10914
          Butler County               20947
          Calhoun County             118572
          Chambers County             34215
          Cherokee County             25989
          Chilton County              43643
          Choctaw County              13859
          Clarke County               25833
          Clay County                 13932
          Cleburne County             14972
          Coffee County               49948
          Colbert County              54428
          Conecuh County              13228
          Coosa County                11539
          Covington County            37765
          Crenshaw County             13906
          Cullman County              80406
          Dale County                 50251
          Dallas County               43820
          DeKalb County               71109
          Elmore County               79303
          Escambia County             38319
          Etowah County              104430
          Fayette County              17241
...                                     ...
Wisconsin Washington County          131887
          Waukesha County            389891
          Waupaca County              52410
          Waushara County             24496
          Winnebago County           166994
          Wood County                 74749
Wyoming   Wyoming                    563626
          Albany County               36299
          Big Horn County             11668
          Campbell County             46133
          Carbon County               15885
          Converse County             13833
          Crook County                 7083
          Fremont County              40123
          Goshen County               13249
          Hot Springs County           4812
          Johnson County               8569
          Laramie County              91738
          Lincoln County              18106
          Natrona County              75450
          Niobrara County              2484
          Park County                 28205
          Platte County                8667
          Sheridan County             29116
          Sublette County             10247
          Sweetwater County           43806
          Teton County                21294
          Uinta County                21118
          Washakie County              8533
          Weston County                7208
```

Now, I want to sort the second index of the dataframe **for a given state** according to the values of the population column. I tried using

```
census_df = census_df.sort('CENSUS2010POP')
```

However, then I get all the values sorted :

```
                         CENSUS2010POP
STNAME   CTYNAME                      
Texas    Loving County              82
Hawaii   Kalawao County             90
Texas    King County               286
         Kenedy County             416
Nebraska Arthur County             460
```

How can I sort the counties according to population **inside each state**? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `census_df.sort_index(level='CITYNAME')` see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_index or `census_df.sort_index(level='CITYNAME', ascending=False)` if you need it sorted from highest to smallest

Comment: @EdChum : Unfortunately, this doesn't give me what I want. I don't want to change the principle index. I want to simply sort the counties inside each state according to their populations which is given as a column.

Comment: @EdChum: It only sorts the county names alphabetically. Rather they should be sorted according to their populations.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, what about `grouping` again after the sort? `census_df = census_df.sort('CENSUS2010POP')` as before and then `census_df.groupby(level=[0,1])`

Comment: @EdChum: I think I couldn't convey it properly. So Let us ask what are the five most populous counties in the state Texas and similarly for the state Nevada and so on. So even if a given county has a smaller population than counties in other states, it should be shown as the first entry for that state if it has highest population in that state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first level `STNAME` and then `apply` function [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for column `CENSUS2010POP`. So `STNAME` stays static and only sorts second level by values of this column:

```
print (census_df.groupby(level=0)['CENSUS2010POP']
                .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())
                .reset_index(level=0,drop=True))
STNAME     CTYNAME          
Alabama    Bullock County         10914
           Choctaw County         13859
           Butler County          20947
           Bibb County            22915
           Clarke County          25833
           Cherokee County        25989
           Barbour County         27457
           Chambers County        34215
           Chilton County         43643
           Autauga County         54571
           Blount County          57322
           Calhoun County        118572
           Baldwin County        182265
           Alabama              4779736
Wisconsin  Waushara County        24496
           Waupaca County         52410
           Wood County            74749
           Washington County     131887
           Winnebago County      166994
           Waukesha County       389891
Wyoming    Crook County            7083
           Big Horn County        11668
           Goshen County          13249
           Converse County        13833
           Carbon County          15885
           Albany County          36299
           Fremont County         40123
           Campbell County        46133
           Wyoming               563626
Name: CENSUS2010POP, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yes. This is right. Can you kindly explain the parts of your command?

Comment: sure, give me a sec.